# How do I parse this data structure returned by Nokogiri in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

So I am cycling through an array element and this is the result returned:

```
[nil, [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x835386d4 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x835385f8 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2961573018.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x835381c0 "Web Designer Full time">]>
```

What I would like to do is access `href` value, and then the `text` value. How do I do that?

I tried this:

```
puts i[:href]
```

But that generates this error:

```
TypeError: Symbol as array index
```

By the way, I am accessing `i` as an element in the array via each like this:

```
contents.each do |i|
    puts i.inspect
    puts i[:href]
end
```

**Edit 1:**

This is how I am generating the `contents` array. There is no need to rename it, because it can get confusing :)

```
contents = {}
first_items.each do |link|
    content_url = link
    content_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(content_url))
    contents[link[:href]] = content_page.css("p a")
end

puts contents.inspect
```

This is what gets output:

```
{nil=>[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fee914 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fee838 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2961573018.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fee400 "Web Designer Full time">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fee298 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fee1bc name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2959813303.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fedd84 "Once in a lifetime opportunity...">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fedc1c name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fedb40 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2925485723.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fed708 "Website Designer and Blogging Internship!">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fed5a0 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fed4c4 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2918424652.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fed08c "Excellent Java Developer Opportunity!">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fecf24 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fece48 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2888669703.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85feca10 "Freelance Graphic Design">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fec8a8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fec7cc name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2900256461.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fec394 "GWT/GXT Developer">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fec22c name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fec150 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2897641463.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85febd18 "Website hiring!">]>]}
```

Here is the full value of the output for `i`:

```
--------------------
This is the value of i: 
[nil, [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fee914 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fee838 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2961573018.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fee400 "Web Designer Full time">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fee298 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fee1bc name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2959813303.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fedd84 "Once in a lifetime opportunity...">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fedc1c name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fedb40 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2925485723.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fed708 "Website Designer and Blogging Internship!">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fed5a0 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fed4c4 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2918424652.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fed08c "Excellent Java Developer Opportunity!">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fecf24 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fece48 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2888669703.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85feca10 "Freelance Graphic Design">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fec8a8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fec7cc name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2900256461.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85fec394 "GWT/GXT Developer">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x85fec22c name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x85fec150 name="href" value="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2897641463.html">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x85febd18 "Website hiring!">]>]]
--------------------
This is the value of i.href:
```

**Edit 2:**

By the way, this is what the actual HTML output looks like...I did this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
    doc.html {
        doc.body {
            contents.each do |el|
                if !el.nil?
                    puts "-" * 20
                    puts "This is the value of el: "
                puts el.inspect

                    puts "-" * 20
                    puts "This is the value of el.href: "           
                 puts el[:href]
                end

                doc.p {
                    doc.a el, :href => el
                    } 
            end     
            }           
        }
end

puts "*" * 50
puts "This is the HTML generated"

puts builder.to_html
```

This is how it looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p><a href="&lt;a%20href=%22http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2961573018.html%22&gt;Web%20Designer%20Full%20time&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a%20href=%22http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2959813303.html%22&gt;Once%20in%20a%20lifetime%20opportunity...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a%20href=%22http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2925485723.html%22&gt;Website%20Designer%20and%20Blogging%20Internship!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a%20href=%22http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2918424652.html%22&gt;Excellent%20Java%20Developer%20Opportunity!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a%20href=%22http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2888669703.html%22&gt;Freelance%20Graphic%20Design&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a%20href=%22http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2900256461.html%22&gt;GWT/GXT%20Developer&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a%20href=%22http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2897641463.html%22&gt;Website%20hiring!&lt;/a&gt;">&lt;a href="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2961573018.html"&gt;Web Designer Full time&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2959813303.html"&gt;Once in a lifetime opportunity...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2925485723.html"&gt;Website Designer and Blogging Internship!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2918424652.html"&gt;Excellent Java Developer Opportunity!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2888669703.html"&gt;Freelance Graphic Design&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2900256461.html"&gt;GWT/GXT Developer&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://bham.craigslist.org/web/2897641463.html"&gt;Website hiring!&lt;/a&gt;</a></p></body></html>
```

Comment: How are you using Nokogiri to get the above array? There's certainly a more direct way to start with the HTML and get the elements you want.

Comment: 'i' is a good name for an index (number). A good name for an element would be 'element' or 'node' or 'el'

Comment: @Mark-Thomas not quite sure I understand what you mean. I am loading a URL into Nokogiri and just scanning the page that is brought in and then running this loop on it.

Comment: @marcamillion You are not selecting <a> tags only? If not, why?

Comment: @ismaelga because I have already parsed the data and stored just the links in the array. Eventually, I will also store the text along with the link in a 2D array...but for now I am just trying to get it working with a single dimensional array.

Comment: That's not an array; that's a hash.

Comment: Ok, do `contents.each do |href, i|`. I'm pretty sure it will unbug your code. Because content.each methods needs a block with 2 params since it's a Hash

Comment: @marcamillion What I am saying is that Nokogiri already parses the page and stores it. It has convenient ways to extract the content. By storing Nokogiri objects yourself and then extracting them from your data structure, you're duplicating functionality and as a result making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be a lot simpler. Nokogiri already parses the document and provides convenient ways to access the content. Rather than looping, storing Nokogiri objects, then trying to extract them, why not try a more direct approach?

Try this code:

```
content_page.search(//a[@href]).map{ |el| [el[:href], el.text] }
```

This creates the 2d array containing the text and href for each link in the document, which is what you said in a follow-up comment that you're actually working toward.

Comment: So `content_page` would be the 2d array? Or would I have to assign this to a new array?

Also...where can I find more about how to interact with the data returned by Nokogiri? The official documentation doesn't seem too helpful for me.

Comment: The output of the above statement is the 2d array you want. Most of it is plain Ruby. It gets all links from Nokogiri, then the `map` creates an inner array, extracting the `href` attribute and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, since you have a odd nil in your array.

```
contents.each do |i|
  if !i.nil?
    puts i.inspect
    puts i[:href]
  end
end
```

**Edit1**: Actually I think you just need to do `contents = contents[1]`.

```
contents = contents[1]
contents.each do |i|
    puts i.inspect
    puts i[:href]
end
```

Comment: This doesn't help me because the nil value isn't my issue. I am trying to figure out how to get at the `href` and `text` values in that hash/array.

Comment: try the `contents = contents[1]` after your each block.

Comment: after the block? i.e. after the last `end`? i.e. outside of the block, or at the end of the block?

Comment: That creates more problems than it helps: `NoMethodError: undefined method ‘each’ for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: I tough contents was an Array, now with your edit it seems to be and Hash? I'm lost

Comment: So confusing! Maybe you should cleanup your question... I think the problem is that your `i` is an array of nodes, will update my answer. It would be good if you tell what `first_items` object is

Answer (score 0):

You can use compact to remove nils:

```
nodes.compact.each do |node|
  puts node[:href], node.text
end
```

Comment: I get an undefined method error with using compact:
`NoMethodError: undefined method ‘compact’ for #<Hash:0x10143a740>`

Comment: I renamed your array to 'nodes' which I think is more descriptive than 'contents'. I'm referring tho the array at the top of your question.

Comment: Heh....I know....that's what I did. I simply added `compact` to my array `contents` and that's the error I get.

Comment: Well your error message says Hash and not Array so that's a clue that you're doing something weird but I can't tell what you're doing.

Comment: I added more info with the way the generated HTML looks.